# How to delete snapshot based on the description?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2

I am trying to delete any previous snapshot with description having `tags_description` , how can i do so ? The following code throws me error :

def call_cleaner(data):
    regions = ['us-west-2', 'eu-central-1', 'ap-southeast-1']

```
for index, region in enumerate(regions):
    for ip_address, tags_descrip, regions_az, volume_id in data[index]:
        ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region, aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY, )
        delete_snapshot = ec2.describe_snapshots(Filters=tags_descrip)
        for snap in delete_snapshot['Snapshots']:
            print "Deleting snapshot %s" % snap['SnapshotId']
            ec2.delete_snapshot(SnapshotId=snap['SnapshotId'])
```

**ERROR**

```
delete_snapshot = ec2.describe_snapshots(Filters=tags_descrip)
AttributeError: 'ec2.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'describe_snapshots'
```

Answer (score -2):

In order to use these functions in boto3 you need to use ec2 client which can be initialized like this: `client = boto3.client('ec2')`. (Basically, replace `ec2.*` with `client.*`

Comment: delete_snapshot = ec2.get_all_snapshots(Filters=tags_descrip)
AttributeError: 'ec2.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'get_all_snapshots'

Comment: Do i also needs to pass the region here with `client = boto3.client('ec2')`  as `client = boto3.client('ec2',region)`

Comment: also i get `Invalid type for parameter Filters, value: pdx02-he-trial-ansible01, type: <type 'str'>, valid types: <type 'list'>, <type 'tuple'>`

Comment: What are your filter values in `tags_descrip`? Please add them to the question.

Comment: they are basically list of tag names that i got from another function

Comment: @NishantSingh You need to format your filters as described here: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_snapshots. The relevant types are "tag", "tag-key", "tag-value". I cannot help any more without the data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116962/discussion-between-nishant-singh-and-dean-fenster).